# Deadlock graph interpretation help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, deadlock, database-administration

A friend of mine has issue with a Java app (Spring+Hibernate) that crushes randomly due to the exception:

> Transaction (Process ID 57) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

I believe that it is due to the abusive use of `@Transactional` annotation. In fact, each single query in his application is an explicit transaction with "read committed" isolation level. I've asked him to provide me with the deadlock graph (see below) however I'm unable to understand it.

If I’m correct: process process1bc993e8108 (select) holds shared lock on table TABLEA. process process1bc9a25bc28 (insert) is waiting to put intent exclusive lock on the table TABLEA. But at the same time the same process holds already intent exclusive lock on the table TABLEA ??? and the process1bc9a10bc28 (select) was chosen victim because it is waiting to put shared lock on TABLEA ??? I'm lost here... for me it is simple blocking and I cannot find here any cycling blocking (aka deadlock)

So, here are my questions:

1. Am I right that this is due to the explicit transactions and moving
   to implicit transactions for single queries would solve the problem?
2. Could activating "snapshot" option for "read committed" be a
   potential solution? or should they decrease transaction isolation level by default and keep the "read committed" for multi commands transactions only?
3. How to reproduce the deadlock graph in SQL
   editor? Should I run `select + insert + select` at the very same time
   to reproduce it?

I would really appreciate any help.

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process1bc9a10bc28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 6:1:2283030 " waittime="1948" ownerId="125034381" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.357" XDES="0x1be848c6040" lockMode="S" schedulerid="5" kpid="7160" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="7" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc994bf848" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1496" schedulerid="1" kpid="7436" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc9a158108" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1499" schedulerid="2" kpid="4624" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="5" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc993e84e8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1498" schedulerid="4" kpid="13552" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc9a2c48c8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1499" schedulerid="3" kpid="9660" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="6" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc993e8108" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2502" schedulerid="4" kpid="15204" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" loginname="xcaf" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc993b1c28" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1497" schedulerid="6" kpid="8708" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc993ceca8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1498" schedulerid="5" kpid="11632" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="3" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.367" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.363" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.363" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125034381" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="18" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x02000000baccf036bb7c864a41cd9425eebee165c997e0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int)select sum(AMOUNT) from TABLEA where IND_REJECT='Y' and ID_BILL= @P0    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1bc9a25bc28" taskpriority="0" logused="35648" waitresource="PAGE: 6:1:5073184 " waittime="2077" ownerId="125033657" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:39.767" XDES="0x1c19a7b0ba0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="6" kpid="13120" status="suspended" spid="69" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.803" lastbatchcompleted="2020-02-26T15:09:44.793" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.793" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="LP097MID8513" hostpid="123" loginname="xcaf" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="125033657" currentdb="6" currentdbname="server1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="1126" stmtend="2768" sqlhandle="0x0200000025025e075b272ac2bce1ec6cdcbc590a955eb7d30000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 int,@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 int,@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 nvarchar(4000),@P8 datetime,@P9 datetime,@P10 decimal(38,2),@P11 nvarchar(4000),@P12 nvarchar(4000),@P13 nvarchar(4000),@P14 nvarchar(4000),@P15 nvarchar(4000),@P16 nvarchar(4000),@P17 nvarchar(4000),@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 nvarchar(4000),@P20 nvarchar(4000),@P21 nvarchar(4000),@P22 nvarchar(4000),@P23 nvarchar(4000),@P24 nvarchar(4000),@P25 nvarchar(4000),@P26 datetime,@P27 nvarchar(4000),@P28 datetime,@P29 nvarchar(4000),@P30 int,@P31 nvarchar(4000),@P32 datetime,@P33 int)insert into dbo.TABLEA (   </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="2283030" dbid="6" subresource="FULL" objectname="server1.dbo.TABLEA" id="lock1be67e3cd00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594048610304">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a25bc28" mode="IX" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc9a10bc28" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8a80" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Consumer" nodeId="5" tid="4" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc994bf848" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8b80" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Consumer" nodeId="5" tid="5" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc9a158108" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8880" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Consumer" nodeId="5" tid="2" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc993e84e8" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8c80" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Consumer" nodeId="5" tid="6" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc9a2c48c8" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8380" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="2" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc993b1c28" />
                <owner id="process1bc993e84e8" />
                <owner id="process1bc993ceca8" />
                <owner id="process1bc994bf848" />
                <owner id="process1bc9a158108" />
                <owner id="process1bc9a2c48c8" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc993e8108" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8780" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Consumer" nodeId="5" tid="1" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc993b1c28" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1bedeed8980" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Consumer" nodeId="5" tid="3" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc9a10bc28" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc993ceca8" />
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="5073184" dbid="6" subresource="FULL" objectname="server1.dbo.TABLEA" id="lock1bf59410980" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594048610304">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1bc993e8108" mode="S" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1bc9a25bc28" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA (

       ID_TABLEA numeric(10,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       ID_BILL numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
       AMOUNT numeric(16,2) NULL,
       IND_REJECT char(1) COLLATE French_CI_AS NULL,
       CONSTRAINT PK__TABLEA__0F1F9EE614270015 PRIMARY KEY (ID_TABLEA),

)
```

Comment: Just to point out that while you *might* be able to solve it, you should really write your application to handle (i.e. retry) in such cases as deadlocks can be common in large complex databases.

Comment: All of the queries specify `ID_BILL` in the `WHERE` clause yet there is no index on that column in the provided DDL. Adding an index will help touch only the rows needed and mitigated the likelihood of deadlocks.